# When does Redis read key from AOF persistence?

Tags: redis

I might be wrong but still asking this question. ;-)
So I am planning to use redis as a persistent storage(Primary Storage). I am having AOF enabled.I know redis will load this data during server start up. Let us say I have 10GB data and 5 GB ram, If I try to search for a key which is not loaded in RAM, will it check AOF and load that data to RAM by offloading any unused keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have less memory than data size in Redis. In your example Redis would run out of memory during start-up. You find more answers here: http://redis.io/topics/faq

Comment: What about Redis VM, I know which is not currently supported in later versions than v2.4 , http://redis.io/topics/virtual-memory

Comment: Well, i don't think it makes sense to build a use-case on a deprecated feature. When it's important for you to have more data then your available RAM you should consider using different DBs then Redis. As example RocksDB very useful on flash disks  MongoDB could also fit for many use-cases